# Accessing a service/thread from different activities

Tags: android

I'm writing a Bluetooth remote control application to control my Bluetooth enabled robot, but I have a hard time understanding the workflow of an Android application. I know what I want, but it's not very easy to do. Other responses haven't been satisfactory.

Here's a rough application layout I want:

[image]

If you have a better idea of how to do this thing I'd be happy to consider.

Mainly my problem is accessing the connection thread/service (whatever the name is) from the connect method of the main activity and from the control activity, how do I pass the reference? I know that the main activity can disappear when in a sub-activity of the application, so I'd have to pass the reference by `getExtra()` probably, but it only takes a `String` variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method you might like to consider is using a [Bound Service.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) This can be made to return an **IBinder** interface, allowing access to the service's public methods. You can make any of your activities bind to the service and thus pass/retrieve data to/from the service.

If you need the service to communicate with the activities immediately (e.g for lost connection), then the service could use **sendBroadcast** to inform activities which had registered a **BroadcastReceiver** to listen for the intent sent in the broadcast.

Comment: Would there be a way to make a general secondary thread to my application where my activities could read/write data? The creation/destruction of activities really makes things complicated...

Comment: The service itself should serve for that. If you bind to the service in each activity's onStart() and unbind in the onStop(), then it will keep running as you switch activities. Once no activities are bound it will stop if you bind each time with Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE.

Comment: Thanks, that's the conclusion I got to as well: I must use a `Service` and bind it every time I start a new `Activity` and unbind it from the last `Activity` that used it (not necessarily in that order).

Comment: I ended up using global variables inside the application class, it seems it isn't used very often. This solution is now clean and I can access my bluetooth device/socket from any activity or helper service without problems.